# Nested stored procedure not working after recompile

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have an odd issue. I have a stored procedure that internally calls another procedure. This has been working without issue for quite some time. Now when I make change to the internal stored procedure and recompile it, the external procedure skips over the internal procedure and throw errors. I have tried debugging it and it just steps over the internal proc and not into it.

The really odd thing is however, if I then run the internal proc on its own either via the client which is Excel or is SMSS. The external proc will then will start to run correctly. I have tried to add WITH RECOMPILE to the procedure calls with any change in behaviour. Any ideas on what is happening?

Comment: Can you explain with some examples

Comment: I second what TheGameiswar said: add the outlines of the SP's in your question, and explain the steps that lead up to the problem in a few concise bullet-points so the sequence of events is clear.

Comment: Could schema name be affecting your perceived versus actual results.   schemaA.InnerSp  vs  schemaB.InnerSp.   Overall it sounds like a security problem in the situation where errors are thrown.  When you use SSMS or Excel and it works what user is being used, when it fails what user is being used.  Take out the with recompile to see if that is hiding the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you have `#temp` tables with the same name in both procedures.

In which case rename them to avoid naming collisions. An example below.

```
CREATE PROC P2
AS 
SELECT 1 AS Y INTO #T
SELECT Y FROM #T

GO

CREATE PROC P1
AS 
SELECT 1 AS X INTO #T
EXEC P2

GO

EXEC P2; /*Run P2 first so the plan is cached*/
EXEC P1; /*This executes fine*/

EXEC sp_recompile 'P2' /*Mark P2 for recompilation*/
EXEC P1 /* Attempt to recompile P2 fails with  "Invalid column name
          'Y' as a table called #T without this column already exists at outer scope."*/
```

Comment: Thank you Martin. That is exactly the problem. I will take care with this one.